# Detect when md panel is bigger than window size

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angularjs-material

This problem is purely CSS, but for the background I am using mdPanel, in material design for angularjs.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oJbPzX?&editable=true

If your browser is relatively small, and you put this height to a big value

```
.menu-panel .menu-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 8px 0;
  height: 100px; <=== here
  overflow-y: auto;
  min-width: 256px;
}
```

You will have the menu outside of the window. This is an example, In my case, I have a mdPanel that is kind of big (you can simulate it by having a big height in codepen, and I would like those behaviors.

1. If the panel is entirely visible, don't show the scrollbar (EASY /
   Already Implemented)
2. If the panel is smaller than the content, show scrollbar  (EASY / Already Implemented)
3. If the panel is bigger or
       going out of the viewport, than add a scrollbar to it so that I can
       navigate the content  (HARD / Not Implemented)

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Add `Height` with `calc`

```
.menu-panel .menu-content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 8px 0;
    height: calc(100vh - 98px);
    overflow-y: auto;
    min-width: 256px;
}
```